# How can I inject Mongo options while initializing MongoClient in Spring core without annotation?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, jakarta-ee

I want to initialize MongoDB cluster connection pool with replica set name so that in case my primary fails and other machine in cluster becomes primary then it should work, something like below :

```
MongoClientOptions options = MongoClientOptions.builder()
                .requiredReplicaSetName("ReplicaSetName").
                build();

ServerAddress serverAddress1 = new ServerAddress("192.168.5.5");
ServerAddress serverAddress2 = new ServerAddress("192.168.5.6"); List<ServerAddress> seeds = new ArrayList<>();
seeds.add(serverAddress1);seeds.add(serverAddress2);
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(seeds,options);
```

Above code works perfectly but I want to do the same in Spring context.xml.

Currently my application context look like this :

```
    <bean id="mongoServerAddr1" class="com.mongodb.ServerAddress">
     <constructor-arg name="host" value="${MONGO_CLUSTER1_HOST1}" />
     <constructor-arg name="port" value="${MONGO_CLUSTER1_PORT1}" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="mongoServerAddr2" class="com.mongodb.ServerAddress">
     <constructor-arg name="host" value="${MONGO_CLUSTER1_HOST2}" />
     <constructor-arg name="port" value="${MONGO_CLUSTER1_PORT2}" />
    </bean>


    <util:list id="mongoHostList" value-type="com.mongodb.ServerAddress">
            <ref bean="mongoServerAddr1" />
            <ref bean="mongoServerAddr2" />
    </util:list>


    <bean id="mongoCredentialIDCluster1" class="com.mongodb.MongoCredential" factory-method="createScramSha1Credential">
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" name="userName" value="${MONGO_CLUSTER1_USER1}" />
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" name="source" value="${MONGO_CLUSTER1_SOURCE1}" />
        <constructor-arg type="char[]" name="password" value="${MONGO_CLUSTER1_PASS1}" />
</bean>

<bean id="mongoCredentialIDCluster2" class="com.mongodb.MongoCredential" factory-method="createScramSha1Credential">
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" name="userName" value="${MONGO_CLUSTER1_USER2}" />
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" name="source" value="${MONGO_CLUSTER1_SOURCE2}" />
        <constructor-arg type="char[]" name="password" value="${MONGO_CLUSTER1_PASS2}" />
</bean>

<util:list id="mongoCredentialList" value-type="com.mongodb.MongoCredential">
            <ref bean="mongoCredentialIDCluster1" />
            <ref bean="mongoCredentialIDCluster2" />
    </util:list>

    <bean id="mongoClient" class="com.mongodb.MongoClient">
            <constructor-arg name="seeds" ref="mongoHostList" />
            <constructor-arg name="credentialsList" ref="mongoCredentialList" />
</bean>
<bean id="mongoDao" class="com.dao.MongoDaoImpl">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongoClient" />
</bean>
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: You should add some information about the issues you're facing with the XML setup e.g. exceptions or the unexpected outcome.

Comment: I tried to inject MongoClientOptions but was unable to do , because it works on builder pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I have solve this problem with MongoClientURI class.
Config details:

```
MONGO_URI=mongodb://user:password@192.168.50.167:27017,192.168.50.169:27017/?authSource=admin&replicaSet=ReplicaSetName
```

This is my application context configuration:

```
    <bean id="mongoURI" class="com.mongodb.MongoClientURI">
        <constructor-arg name="uri" value="${MONGO_URI}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mongoCLIENT" class="com.mongodb.MongoClient">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongoURI" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="mongoDao" class="com.dao.MongoDaoImpl">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongoCLIENT" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/):

The example in the Spring Docs is:

***Code***

```
<beans>

  <mongo:mongo-client host="localhost" port="27017">
    <mongo:client-options connections-per-host="8"
                   threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier="4"
                   connect-timeout="1000"
                   max-wait-time="1500}"
                   auto-connect-retry="true"
                   socket-keep-alive="true"
                   socket-timeout="1500"
                   slave-ok="true"
                   write-number="1"
                   write-timeout="0"
                   write-fsync="true"/>
  </mongo:mongo-client>

</beans>
```

***Replica Set XML Example***

```
<mongo:mongo-client id="replicaSetMongo" replica-set="127.0.0.1:27017,localhost:27018"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How can I pass multiple hosts and ports and credentails with replicaset name?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how you could configure a replica set.